# Servo stabilizer with variac and buck boost transformer

Tags: transformer

I have a servo stabilizer like the drawing below:

[image: Servo Stabilizer]

The drawing above is not probably not entirely correct because the fixed tap is at one end of the variac, thus correction will happen only either for increasing input voltage or decreasing input voltage but not both.

For correction in both directions the fixed tap would have to be somewhere towards the center of the variac.

How does one set the position of the fixed tap?

For example, if the input voltage is between 190V and 280V, and the output voltage is to be 240V, how would one set the tap position?

Comment: If you can't modify the variac then you can't add a tap.

Comment: Is the variac of this kind? figure 16 of this: https://variac.com/staco/PDFCutSheets/VT%20Schematic.pdf . Don' forget that a sliding tap makes a short at some positions ...

Comment: <<< correction will happen only either for increasing input voltage or decreasing input voltage >>> increase/decrease OUTPUT voltage, for this 2 or more taps are needed?

Comment: @Andyaka i can modify the variac , by scraping the enamel and soldering a wire for the fixed tap.The fixed end of the buck boost can be connected anywhere on the variac, while the other end of the buck boost is connected to the slider of the variac. Hence my query was about how to set the fixed tap.

Comment: @Antonio51 Just one tap would be needed AFAIK. When the wiper is on one side of the tap the buck boost txfer voltage would add to the supply mains and when it is on the other side it would subtract from the mains voltage , thus regulating the output.

Comment: Have you tried simulating this circuit?

Comment: I did not simulate it, will try it.

Comment: I have tried to simulate this kind of variac, unless I made an error. Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDCWd.png Values to be adapted.

Comment: @EmbSysDev Yes, I would say 1 fix tap and 1 wiper. The example I show would be ok with the wiper limited to some shift. Enjoy this circuit. Made with http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if the input voltage is between 190V and 280V, and the output voltage is to be 240V, how would one set the tap position?

That really depends on the ratio of the buck-boost transformer. It's not 1:1, otherwise there'd be no point to it. The reason for the buck-boost transformer is to use a lower power autotransformer, since it only needs to accommodate for the power added in the buck/boost transformer.

The higher the buck-boost ratio, the cheaper the autotransformer.

If the input voltage is between 190V and 280V, the buck boost will have to:

- add up to 50V (190V -> 240V)
- subtract up to 40V (280V -> 240V).

We'd like to use the full range of motion on the autotransformer, but we also want the buck-boost primary to survive startup in the worst-case condition of the wiper being in the entirely wrong location.

The control circuit can disconnect the secondary, e.g. using a relay, when the regulated voltage is too far out of spec.

The buck-boost needs then a primary rated at 280V, and a 19:5 ratio, i.e. 190V to 50V.

The B-C section of the autotransformer (see below) needs to be scaled so that it reduces 280V to 40/50*190V, so 152 relative to A-B's 280, or a 19:35 ratio.

The schematic would thus look as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwltSL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- 190V input: wiper at A; 50V is added to the input.
- 240V input: wiper at B; 0V is added to the input.
- 280V input: wiper at C; 40V is subtracted from the input.

Those three operating points can be visualized:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY90CK.png)</sup>

Comment: Is point C on auto transformer floating ?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a full sliding wiper, a fixed tap at ~ 85% would solve the specifications (190 V min -> 280 V max).
NB: be careful when the input voltage is 280 V ("overvoltage" input), and when it is 190 V ("overcurrent" input).

The wiper will need to slide from 70% to quasi 100%.

The picture simulation is in the case of 190V -> wiper at 98%.

[image]

Other case ...

[image]

Comment: thanks for the simulation. Do you have similar simulation with LTSPICE, else I will try to do it. Just a few clarifications : you have "tap = 0.98" for giving room for over travel of the wiper ? what is LL3 = 0 for ? you have buck boost transformer at unity ratio ?

Comment: LL3 is only needed if wiper "travel" is not "full". Yes, Buck-boost transformer is unity ratio. I had to use 0.99 or 0.999 because the simulator does not like the "1" ratio (logical, because there are only inductors in this schematic, and if these are "perfect", there is a "matrix" problem).

Comment: For input of 190V rms, If tap = 1 in place of 0.98, the output voltage would be 271 V rms, so change very quickly! Therefore, one must be careful, or change some specifications, within the "step" voltage of the wiper, or lock the "max" position mechanically.